# Button on bottom of image with parameter adjustViewBounds Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a button on bottom of an image with the parameter `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

This is what I'm looking for:

[image: I need this]

But this is what I'm getting:

[image: But I have this]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" //i really need this parameter because the height of each image is different
        android:src="@drawable/homero" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="See more"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: FYI: I've moved your images inline so they're easier to evaluate. I also adjusted your XML to use more consistent indentation. Finally, I replaced some of your more generic tags (e.g., `image`, `xml`) with `android-studio` and `android-layout`, which is more likely to get this in front of contributors that can help you solve this.

Comment: Thanks!! my english is really bad

Comment: Having just spent a year in countries where I didn’t speak many of the languages very well, I sympathize. But you’re doing fine; we understood what you meant, and it looks like you’ve gotten a good answer. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Jeremy!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your ImageView and Button to be overlapping, they either need to reference each other, or have the same layout alignment.

In this example, aligning your Button to the bottom of your ImageView will resolve this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/homero" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/idImg"
        android:text="See more"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The way you currently have it, your button is trying to get to the bottom of your RelativeLayout. Because your RelativeLayout has a height of `wrap_content`, it just keeps growing as the button tries to get to the bottom, eventually filling the screen!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this really helps me!!